# jQuery Unable To Find Existing Div Outside of Drupal Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, find, element

I'm experiencing a kind of specific issue which I'm hoping can be generalized.

I'm trying to use jQuery to alter a div with **id="footer-wrapper"** that I know exists.

When trying to do this from within a node in Drupal, jQuery can't seem to find the element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("div with id=\"page\" has length: " + ($("#page").length));
    alert("div with id=\"footer-wrapper\" has length: " + ($("#footer-wrapper").length));
</script>
```

However it can find the div with **id="page"**, which is also outside the node body. I don't understand why it would be able to find one and not the other.

Here is a **[rather messy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfCcA/)** and here is a **[link to the actual page](http://www.nba.com/warriors/jquery-element-testing)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably being called before the footer is loaded. Have you tried wrapping it with:

```
$(document).ready(function({
     [alert statements]
});
```

Comment: hmmm i've been using head.ready() from head.js because I was under the impression it encompassed $(document).ready() because of [an answer to a another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221122/head-ready-vs-document-ready). I guess not :/